# Get a list of fields from a list of shapefiles

Tags: arcpy, fields-attributes, for-loop, if-else

I am trying to get a list of fields from every shapefile in a list I have created that's stored in a variable. My prof says I should be able to call that variable in my if/else statement within my for loop to get this, but I'm having trouble and keep getting an OS error saying my list does not exist.

As I understand it based on the Esri documentation page, ListFields() is supposed to just be for a file name?

The code works until I get to this part.

Does anyone have any insight?

Code is as follows:

```
UTM = []
noUTM = []
for fc in filename:
    filename = list(arcpy.ListFeatureClasses(feature_type='point'))
    sp_ref = arcpy.Describe(fc)
    spatial_ref = arcpy.Describe(fc).spatialReference.name
    if spatial_ref == srs:
        arcpy.management.AddXY(fc)
        UTM.append(fc)
        [field.name for field in arcpy.ListFields(filename)]
    else:
        noUTM.append(fc)
print(UTM)
print(noUTM)
```

Comment: For starters, it looks like you are looping over filename before it is even defined.

Comment: Alongside what @bixb0012 identifies you also create a list of field names but don't assign it to a variable.

Comment: Please do not delete and repost Questions.